# Как распознать текст в случайном наборе символов?

Tags: python, алгоритм, машинное-обучение

Необходимо из набора случайных символов извлечь слова содержащие имена, фамилии и т.д. Например, из такого набора слов:

```
3kshjfsdhf9834r
Henry11
34r9jsadfsdf
Jackson33
3d2d32ddffjkj
Alex
```

получить вот такой:

```
Henry11
Jackson33
Alex
```

Пока что думаю считать гласные и согласные в словах, и далее оставлять слова с определенным соотношением гласных и согласных. Второй вариант - это использовать словарь, но не уверен, что есть словарь со всеми именами и фамилиями, еще и русские имена и фамилии надо учесть.

Возможно есть какое то готовое решение из "модного" мира машинного обучения?

Comment: чтобы реализовать первый вариант, нужно будет сделать сначала второй :) - простого пути нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Пока что думаю считать гласные и согласные в словах, и далее оставлять
> слова с "определенным" соотношением гласных и согласных.

Например, исключаем слова, у которых от 4 и более подряд идущих согласных:

```
import re

PATTERN = re.compile('[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]{4,}', flags=re.I)

words = ['3kshjfsdhf9834r', 'Henry11', '34r9jsadfsdf', 'Jackson33', '3d2d32ddffjkj', 'Alex']
print(words)

new_words = [word for word in words if not PATTERN.search(word)]
print(new_words)  # ['Henry11', 'Jackson33', 'Alex']
```

**PS.**

Понятно, что этот алгоритм очень простой

Comment: Спасибо, хорошая идея.

Comment: И сразу отбрасывается, например, фамилия Schwarzenegger. :)

Comment: @Yaant, ага и большая часть других немецких слов :)

Comment: понятно, что будут ошибки, но идея в нужном направлении

Answer (score 3):

Если у вас есть большой - ОЧЕНЬ большой, порядка тысяч или десятков тысяч  - набор реальных имен и фамилий,то попытаться использовать - как вы говорите - "модное" машинное обучение можно.

Примерно так.

Сначала генерируем еще один - столь же большой - набор случайных последовательностей. Потом перемешиваем два наших набора ("правильных" и случайных), не забыв приписать каждому слову соответствующую метку. Затем пытаемся  обучить нейронную сеть задаче классификации. Входные признаки - буква последовательностей и n-грамы (возможно - что то еще, но сейчас в голову не приходит, надо думать). Есть  надежда, что сеть удастся обучить.

Кстати, тогда и проблема "четырех согласных", но не произвольных, а таких, которые действительно встречаются в данном языке, будет по ходу решена.

Кстати по ходу, не совсем понятно, что означают цифры после имени-фамилии в вашем примере и насколько они значимы.

P.S. Вот еще нашел ссылочку - http://ai-news.ru/2018/11/pytorch_rnn_opredelyaem_yazyk_po_familii_cheloveka.html
Задача хотя и немного отличная от вашей, но думаю, некоторые полезные идеи можно почерпнуть.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, осталось узнать про "нейронные сети" вообще)) цифры в конце ничего не значат, просто набор символов

Comment: статья реально полезная. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле все довольно просто:

```
Для каждой строки в файле:
    Для каждой подряд идущей комбинации букв в строке: 
         #(word) -> (w, wo, wor, word, o, or, ord, rd, r, rd, d)
         Чекаем являться ли эта комбинция именем(через списки имен или либой например)
```

Вообще говоря было б неплохо, если бы вы дали часть набора. Я в вашем примере вижу закономерности с цифрами, но не могу понять оно так и есть, или это дефект примера

Comment: А фамилии через что чекать будем?

Comment: @passant чем отличеться фамилия Дверь от слова дверь? Если ничем, то проверки того что слово корректное будет достаточно

Comment: @ Andrio Skur - Не совсем понял. Да, вы говорите, что если слово корректно, то оно может быть фамилией. Но это не сняло основного вопроса -  а если фамилия не совпадает с корректным словом, как ее распознать? Откуда взять такой список. Кстати, если такой список вдруг есть -  то задача вообще становиться тривиальной. Но подозреваю, что такого списка, особенно на разных языках, создать нельзя.

Comment: вариант работы через список словарей - это просто. Вся проблема в том что такого словаря нет, нужны же имена в транслите, английские имена и т.д..тут явно нужен анализ текста.

Comment: @garrythehotdog можете дать пример данных побольше?